# Query an alphabetically ordered list of all names in OCCUPATIONS Table

Tags: mysql

Generate the following two result sets:

1.Query an alphabetically ordered list of all names in OCCUPATIONS, immediately followed by the first letter of each profession as a parenthetical (i.e.: enclosed in parentheses). For example: AnActorName(A), ADoctorName(D), AProfessorName(P), and ASingerName(S).
2.Query the number of ocurrences of each occupation in OCCUPATIONS. Sort the occurrences in ascending order, and output them in the following format:

There are a total of [occupation_count] [occupation]s.
where [occupation_count] is the number of occurrences of an occupation in OCCUPATIONS and [occupation] is the lowercase occupation name. If more than one Occupation has the same [occupation_count], they should be ordered alphabetically.

Note: There will be at least two entries in the table for each type of occupation.

Input Format

The OCCUPATIONS table is described as follows:Occupation will only contain one of the following values: Doctor, Professor, Singer or Actor.

Sample Input

An OCCUPATIONS table that contains the following records:

Sample Output

Ashely(P)
Christeen(P)
Jane(A)
Jenny(D)
Julia(A)
Ketty(P)
Maria(A)
Meera(S)
Priya(S)
Samantha(D)
There are a total of 2 doctors.
There are a total of 2 singers.
There are a total of 3 actors.
There are a total of 3 professors.

Generate the following two result sets:

1.Query an alphabetically ordered list of all names in OCCUPATIONS, immediately followed by the first letter of each profession as a parenthetical (i.e.: enclosed in parentheses). For example: AnActorName(A), ADoctorName(D), AProfessorName(P), and ASingerName(S).
2.Query the number of ocurrences of each occupation in OCCUPATIONS. Sort the occurrences in ascending order, and output them in the following format:

There are a total of [occupation_count] [occupation]s.
where [occupation_count] is the number of occurrences of an occupation in OCCUPATIONS and [occupation] is the lowercase occupation name. If more than one Occupation has the same [occupation_count], they should be ordered alphabetically.

Note: There will be at least two entries in the table for each type of occupation.

Input Format

The OCCUPATIONS table is described as follows:Occupation will only contain one of the following values: Doctor, Professor, Singer or Actor.

Sample Input

An OCCUPATIONS table that contains the following records:

Sample Output

Ashely(P)
Christeen(P)
Jane(A)
Jenny(D)
Julia(A)
Ketty(P)
Maria(A)
Meera(S)
Priya(S)
Samantha(D)
There are a total of 2 doctors.
There are a total of 2 singers.
There are a total of 3 actors.
There are a total of 3 professors.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [share what you have managed to produce so far](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example"), so that the community can help you overcome the difficulties you are experiencing.

Answer (score -1):

I assume that you have table something like that:

```
CREATE TABLE OCCUPATIONS (
  Name VARCHAR(255),
  Occupation VARCHAR(255)
);

SELECT CONCAT(Name, '(', LEFT(Occupation, 1), ')')
FROM OCCUPATIONS
ORDER BY Name;

SELECT CONCAT('There are a total of ', COUNT(*), ' ', LOWER(Occupation), 's.')
FROM OCCUPATIONS
GROUP BY Occupation
ORDER BY COUNT(*), Occupation;
```

Here working example:

https://sqlfiddle.com/mysql/online-compiler?id=d3240cf0-f53f-463f-97af-6a7cce7c9ef5